# mp3 file not playing in the app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play this song via server but its not playing up only the seekbar is moving from start to end and no info. is shown and song is also not playing.
My code of the player activity is:

**MyPlayer.java**

```
public class MyPlayer extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, View.OnTouchListener {

    @Nullable
    AudioManager audioManager;
    ImageButton nextButton,backButton,repeat,volumehigh,volumelow, playpause;
    ToggleButton shufful;
    SeekBar seekbar, seekbar1;
    TextView artistname,mp3ename,starttime,totaltime;
    String strText= "" ,strText1="";
    MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private int mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds; // this value contains the song duration in milliseconds. Look at getDuration() method in MediaPlayer class
    public EditText editTextSongURL;
    String url = "https://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3";

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private SeekBar seekBarProgress;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player, container, false);
        initView();
        ArtistSong songFromArtist = new ArtistSong();
        strText = songFromArtist.getMp3();
        strText1 = songFromArtist.getName();

        artistname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameArtistaa);
        mp3ename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mp3Nameaa);
        totaltime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.totalTimeaa);
        starttime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.startTimeaa);
        playpause = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.pauseaa);
        nextButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.forwardaa);
        backButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.backaa);
        repeat = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.loopaa);
        shufful = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.icnshuffleaa);
        volumehigh = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.icnvolumehightaa);
        volumelow = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.lowvolumeaa);
        seekbar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBaraa);
        seekbar1 = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar2aa);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        seekbar1.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

        seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {

                // textview.setText("Media Volume : " + i);

                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, i, 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });  
        return view;
    }

    private void initView() {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    /** Method which updates the SeekBar primary progress by current song playing position*/
    private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {
        seekBarProgress.setProgress((int) (((float) mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds)*100));
        // This math construction give a percentage of "was playing"/"song length"
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.pauseaa){
            /** ImageButton onClick event handler. Method which start/pause mediaplayer playing */
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url.toString());
                // setup song from https://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3 URL to mediaplayer data source
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                // you must call this method after setup the datasource in setDataSource method. After calling prepare() the instance of MediaPlayer starts load data from URL to internal buffer.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration(); // gets the song length in milliseconds from URL

            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.start();
                playpause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            }else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                playpause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            }

            primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
        }
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.seekBaraa){
            /** Seekbar onTouch event handler. Method which seeks MediaPlayer to seekBar primary progress position*/
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
                int playPositionInMillisecconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100) * sb.getProgress();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        /** MediaPlayer onCompletion event handler. Method which calls then song playing is complete*/
        playpause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        /** Method which updates the SeekBar secondary progress by current song loading from URL position*/
        seekBarProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could be because you are not waiting for `onPrepared()` callback before calling `mediaPlayer.start()`.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to correct my mistake?? @Abbas

Comment: Check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40217601/1889768).

Answer (score 0):

I have removed some of the unnecessary code to show the changes. I've also changed where `OnBufferingUpdateListener` and `OnErrorListener` are set. Introduced a few new callbacks (use of which are entirely up to you except `OnPrepare()`).

Now what I guess is happening is that you haven't waited for `MediaPlayer` to load i.e. `MediaPlayer` is not ready for playback. [MediaPlayer.OnPrepareListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html#onPrepared(android.media.MediaPlayer)) tells you that `MediaPlayer` is ready for playback.

From the above link:

> **void onPrepared** (MediaPlayer mp)
>
> Called when the media file is ready for playback.

```
public class MyPlayer extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, View.OnTouchListener {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    String url = "https://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player, container, false);
        initView();
        .
        .
        .
        return view;
    }

    private void initView() {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.pauseaa){
            /** ImageButton onClick event handler. Method which start/pause mediaplayer playing */

            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url.toString());
                // setup song from https://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3 URL to mediaplayer data source
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                // you must call this method after setup the datasource in setDataSource method. After calling prepare() the instance of MediaPlayer starts load data from URL to internal buffer.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.start();
                playpause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
            }else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                playpause.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            }

            primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

        mp.start();

        mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mp.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working and hence the desired solution isn't yet achieved, thanks for the help !! :(

Comment: Try the following line instead `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(url));` In the same solution.

Comment: Works for me, Why don't you add any logs you are getting in the question. Also make sure you've added the internet permission. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in manifest file.

Comment: I already added the permission and there is not a single error or anything in the logcat, its showing that

Comment: 10-24 18:22:04.761     187-4522/? E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 44
10-24 18:22:04.971      187-606/? E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 65
10-24 18:22:05.001      187-236/? E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 38
10-24 18:22:05.281     187-1171/? E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 54
10-24 18:22:07.311      535-535/? E/lights﹕ [LED] open path fail.
10-24 18:22:07.831      535-612/? E/lights﹕ [LED] open path fail.
10-24 18:22:11.371      535-535/? E/lights﹕ [LED] open path fail.

Comment: I've used the same code, same link to play and it is working for me. The reason I asked you to post logs in the *Question* is so they are formatted and easily readable. Regardless the logs you provided are completely useless because they are not `MediaPlayer`'s Logs.

Comment: there was a missing line of code of onClickListener, its been figured out.